# Changing coordinates of shapefile using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, shapefile, arcgis-10.1, coordinates

I have a shapefile that has meters as coordinates, and these do not reference world datums or projections.

Is there a way to assign completely new coordinates to the shapefile so that they align with normal WGS1984 datums and I can open this file along with other maps?

The file I am using is one of the layers from the map on this link: 
https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=103b63dcc9f448acbd63f22b728b1a02

Comment: Hello and Welcome! As a new user, please take the [tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: If you want to reproject your data use the "project" tool from arcmap toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

First, confirm the coordinate system of your data by right clicking on the layer and going to Source. In this case, it shows as the following

```
Projected Coordinate System:    WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere
Projection: Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere False_Easting:    0.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000 Central_Meridian:    0.00000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    0.00000000 Auxiliary_Sphere_Type:   0.00000000
Linear Unit:    Meter

Geographic Coordinate System:   GCS_WGS_1984 Datum:     D_WGS_1984 Prime
Meridian:   Greenwich Angular Unit:     Degree
```

To change the coordinate system to match another dataset, use the [Project tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/coverage-toolbox/project.htm), found in Data Management.  The important thing to remember is that you need to Project (change the projection) rather than Defining a projection, as the latter will give you the wrong output.

If you already have a dataset whose coordinate system you wish to match, there's an option on the output coordinate system selection dialog box to Import.

[image]